# .htpasswd asking for authentication on the whole site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

[The screen shot from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNksf.jpg)I use Vultr wordpress one click installation service . they have .htaccess file to protect me to login in wp-admin , but today after I changed the theme , it asks for authentication on all the pages of my site . I don't get any error after I click cancel the authentication window , similar problem as this guy https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103697/htpasswd-asking-for-authentication-on-home-page

I check the .htaccess file on my site , I found it is empty , there is no code there . What should I do to solve the problem .

You could see the popup window by visiting my site : www.hermoart.com

Sincerely looking for help ;(

Comment: Did you ask Vultr for your problem ?

Comment: Their support is horrible , they can only copy and paste , use template :(

Comment: their staff wrote me that they can't help , there is no technical support , I m so disappointed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correct about using WordPress one click application when deploy new server then they're not using Apache but Nginx, so `.htaccess` files is useless.

Your website have a request to https://www.hermoart.com/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.min.js?ver=5.1.1, which causing this issue.

---

From Vultr docs: https://www.vultr.com/docs/one-click-wordpress

### Removing wp-admin Login Prompt

For security purposes, your WordPress app has an initial login prompt that opens when accessing the `/wp-admin/` page. To remove this prompt, follow these steps.

1. Login to your server using ssh as root.
2. Create a backup of your vhost files: `cp /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf /root/`
3. Edit both vhost files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. You need to remove the block of code that starts with `location ^~ /wp-admin/`. It is about 15 lines long.
4. Save your changes, and restart the web server: `systemctl restart nginx.service` && `systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service` (PHP version may vary)

Comment: And yes , it is nginx , my fault , .htaccess should not work , but for nginx , which file does this authentication ? I m quite a newbie :/   And I did removed the the code as their documentation described , but it still popups :((

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot , so the home page is calling the wp-admin . That cause the problem , right

Comment: I have solved the problem , it is right to follow the instruction of Vultr document , that to delete the codes . The reason why I didn't success earlier is that I didn't notice the Cerbot rewrite a server script below the original server script , I just only deleted that particular codes in the orginal server script :/   Thank you sooo much Anh anyway ! ^^

Comment: Btw is it safe for my site to do this action ? that disable the authentication :/ I seriously need to figure it out , coz it is commercial website , it is horrible if my site get hacked , my client gotta sue me terribly :/